# Problem with installation

Tags: database, error, installation, exception, version

I have an old and a new version of Magento 2 installed. However, I have to use the old version because the server only supports PHP 5. After installing this error has appeared.
[image]

After that I tried to execute the suggested command. However, I get this error message.
[image]

What can I do that Magento 2 works?